# Camel REST (restlet) URL - confusing with path params

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel Rest (with restlet component) and I have the following APIs:

```
rest("/order")
    .get("/{orderId}").produces("application/json")
        .param().dataType("int").type(RestParamType.path).name("orderId").endParam()
    .route()
    .bean(OrderService.class, "findOrderById")
    .endRest()


    .get("/customer").produces("application/json").route()
    .bean(OrderService.class, "findOrderByCustomerId")
    .endRest()
```

The problem is that the /order/customer doesn't works (see Exception below). The parameters for /customer comes from JWT...

> java.lang.String to the required type: java.lang.Long with value
>   customer due Illegal characters: customer

I think that camel is confusing the ../{orderId} parameter with .../customer.
If I change the /customer for /customer/orders it's works.

The same idea in Spring Boot could have done with:

```
@RequestMapping("/order/{orderId}")
public Order getOrder(@PathVariable Long orderId) {
    return orderRepo.findOne(orderId);
}

@RequestMapping("/order/customer")
public List<Order> getOrder() {
    return orderRepo.listOrderByCustomer(1l);
}
```

Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order of your GET operations in the Camel Rest DSL. The restlet component has some *issues* in matching the best possible methods.

There is a couple of JIRA tickets related to this:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12320
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7906

Comment: Works like a charm. TKS Claus.